# color pandas dataframe output in ipython console

Tags: python, pandas, termcolor

In R there is a package named `colorout` that allows dataframes to be printed with color (ie numbers appear one color, strings another, etc.). Is there anything similar for the jupyter console? I ran across `termcolor` but that seems slightly different in that it won't color the output by default but rather requires you to use it's functions (so if you just type `df` it still appears white).

Comment: Take a look at the [`Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) class from the `pandas` library. It allows formatting (including coloring) DataFrames.

Comment: this is fine but this means you have to apply your style to each dataframe that you create. i'm hoping for something that colors numbers, for example, regardless if they are in your df or if it's just a number

Comment: @TomasFarias, the styles referenced by your hyperlink only work when the `pd.DataFrame` is rendered as html